# Creating own UI with own buttons (not pre-defined ones). What type of object are they?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface

I am pretty new to Objective-C, but I have (at least a little bit of) experience with cocos2d and sprites. But what really are buttons in my basic View-based application (not cocos2d) ? Is it a view or Image View or what is it ?

---

**Ignore the above**

I want an own image to be a button. How would I put it on screen and let it respond to touch gestures ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIButton` inherits from `UIControl` which inherits from `UIView` which inherits from `UIResponder` which inherits from `NSObject`. Both `UISwitch` and `UISegmentedControl` have the same hierarchy.

For any class, you can check the inheritance hierarchy by looking in the Apple Class Reference. For example, have a look at the [UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).

If you want to create a custom `UIButton`, then you can subclass `UIControl`. However, if all you want is to customize the look of the button, then you can use `UIButtonTypeCustom` and use the `– setBackgroundImage:forState:` method of `UIButton` to set the background to whatever `UIImage` you like.

Comment: So if i use UIButtonTypeCustom and set the backgroundImage to an own image, am I restricted to the bounds of the button (so my image will be fitted into the rounded rectangle? Or can I use the whole rectangle that would be the bounds of the button?

Answer (score 1):

Standard buttons in iOS are usually objects of type [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

In a way, buttons are also views, since a UIButton inherits from UIView.

Comment: I clearly couldn't convey my message, sorry. I'll try it once again. I want an own image to be a button. If I want to make it appear on the screen and respond to touch gestures how would I do that? Make a view with certain proportions and make it touch enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnImage.png"];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]//normal state image
```

This is how you set an image background to the button.There is no UIImageButton or similar class in iOS SDK.